# How do I create an IF ELSE statement if there are no Jekyll posts in a category?

Tags: jekyll

I have a FOR statement that outputs all posts of type `jobs`.

```
{% for post in site.categories.jobs %}
  <article>
    <h3><a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
    <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

But if there are no published posts in `jobs` I would like to display a "We're not hiring right now" message.

Can you create an IF/ELSE statement to check for posts in a specific category?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try check it with `{% if site.categories.jobs == null %}`.

```
{% if site.categories.jobs == null %}
  <p>We're not hiring right now</p>
{% else %}
  {% for post in site.categories.jobs %}
    <article>
      <h3><a href="{{ post.permalink }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
      <p>{{ post.summary }}</p>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Jekyll uses the [Liquid Template Language](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) for future reference, too.